# SharePoint 2010 - SharePoint Designer notification: The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that does not exist

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, error

Upon opening a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010 I receive the following notification in SharePoint Designer:

> The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that
>   does not exist. Some actions will not be available. The assembly
>   strong name is Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Contact your server
>   administrator for more information.

I'm running SharePoint 2010.

Does anyone know how to solve this notification?

Relevant articles:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/d939cbb9-a48d-4d39-9717-ff8586af20db/
- http://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=6504181801110055094&postID=7104288518213734231

Answer (score 4):

Go to your hive folder:

Then into Template\1033\workflow

and find WSS.ACTIONS

Inside there will be a reference to a custom DLL, find it and remove it and your designer should start working again.

Make sure you take a backup of the file first.

Happy hunting.

Comment: I should locate this DLL file on the SharePoint server or on my client computer where SharePoint Designer is installed?

Comment: Just need to remove it from the WSS.ACTIONS file really, the point is the DLL is missing.

Comment: But it's unclear to me on which computer.

Comment: It is most likely the local copy, not sure if this issue effects remote servers. I'm afraid I would say look locally first. Internally created DLLs are easy enough to spot.

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to remove files from the SharePoint webserver. I might try this as a last resort and will post feedback if I do try it.

Comment: It's not removing a file, it's removing a bad reference to a file. The WSS.ACTIONS file is pointing to a DLL that doesn't exist on the server so you are receiving a workflow error. The entire issue is a file HAS been removed somehow and not by the method that was used to place it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the SharePoint Designer caches:

- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

Comment: I cleared "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache" and "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache" the last line did not exist. Requested feedback from end-user.

Comment: Clearing these caches did not resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the quick fix for your problem is to [download the assembly](http://www.zhaodll.co/m/20130509/194067.html). and deploy this in the gac using [GACUTIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah', i'm not planning on implementing DLL files found on the internet.

Comment: yeah, I wont do that myself either. I'm just suggesting quick thing and as you know quick thing usually is not the best track to take. Maybe you can try to reinstall your SharePoint then maybe repair or something :)