Can't open migrated sp2010 wfs and can't create new workflows on SP 2016 On-premise
Good day!
We still have SP 2010 and installed a new SP Server 2016 Farm for migration.
In SP Server 2016 we can't create new workflows or edit the migrated SP2010 workflows using Sharepoint Designer 2010 or 2013. No errors are popping up when creating New Workflow and when editing the migrated workflow it only says "SharePoint Designer cannot display the item". I already tried to do the Cache clear but nothing happens. Do I still need to install the Workflow Manager?


How did you migrate? Using a third party solution like ShareGate to skip 2013? If you are using the content database attach migration method you need to upgrade to SharePoint 2013 first. The Workflow manager is a stand alone product and is not needed for 2010 workflows.

I think you can give a try to install workflow manager to get SharePoint 2013 workflow.

Hi @Christoffer we are currently using the trial version of ShareGate (we've used this software in my previous company and no issues on migrated wfs from sp2010 to sp2016).

hi @Allen_MSFT, i was able to create new, save, and modify the sp2010 workflows now without installing workflow manager. i forgot to save the link to that one comment where they suggested to disable the Site Collections Features: SP 2007 Workflow and Workflows then enable the SP 2007 Workflow first before Workflows. After re-enable i did the Cache clean up listed here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/69261/112355 and it started to work.
